# Have separate page number per master page side spread-sheet in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout, master-page

So I have a document with page spreads, let's say left page has master page A set, and right page has master page B. This for all subsequent pages. 
A-B, A-B, and so forth.

What I want is to have all pages with Master A to have their own numbering counter like "A-1" "A-2" and so on, same thing for B masters.
I've tried with sections but its quite tedious to have to select every single page and specify "apply this section and start with number 'X' ", since I can't to find a way to bind a section automatically to a Master Page.

**Update for better explaination**

As of now my situation is this:

[image: Document master page setup]

placing a page indicator in each master page unfortunately produced page numbers subsequentially every page with something like (consider `|` as page delimiter):

```
| A-1 | B-2 |   I  spread
| A-3 | B-4 |   II spread
...
```

and so on... what I need is to have a separate numbering for every master page like this

```
| A-1 | B-1 |   I  spread
| A-2 | B-2 |   II spread
...
```

Any proper way of doing this? I'm using Indesign CS6 on windows 7.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood you correctly then it is simple. All you need to do is create a text box that will hold the page number in you master page, it should have the static text written first "A-" for example and then the Current Page Number Marker.

Let me know if you need further clarifications!

Comment: That is exactly my current setup, I've update my question to better explain this, thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

One solution I was thinking of is by using one master instead of two (don't forget that you can still set up page guides differently for each page in each master)

In the master, first image below, create a text box that will span on both pages. Now you can write A - (Page Number Marker) then press Shift-Tab to create a right indent tab to shift the cursor to the right side and then write B - (Page Number Marker)

In second page you see the result.

Let me know, Mamoon Tayih

[image: Master A]

[image: Page 2-3]

Comment: Sorry for the delay in the response! In the end I've manually set the pages: following revisions drastically reduced the number of pages to be set side-by-side, so I opted for a dirty manual way.
Your suggestion is quite ingenius, but you would still have the problem of sequent spreads pages, you would have something like "A-2 | B-2" and then in the next spread "A-4 | B-4" since the next page you place the page counter marker is page number 4 in the sequence.